# java.io.FileNotFoundException. Trying to pass in args[0]

Tags: java

I've been trying to convert my C++ code into Java and I'm getting stuck particularly on the file input.

```
String inputfilename = args[0];
    Scanner infile = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(inputfilename));
```

This keeps giving me a java.io.FileNotFoundException error. My file that I'm trying to pass in "StackData.txt" is put correctly into the command line arguements. I've put it in the root directory and the project\src\ folder, and neither are working for me. I've tried to name the inputfilename string and do   like -

```
String inputfilename = "StackData.txt";
Scanner infile = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(inputfilename));
```

and that doesn't seem to work either. Neither does trying to throw the directory path into the string name also. Am I making a really juvenile error somewhere?

I've tried using

```
File infile = new File(args[0]);
```

as well but if I try to use a method for my while loop

```
while (infile.hasNextInt()){ blah blah
 }
```

it says the method cannot be resolved, which I figured means to use the hasNextInt() method I have to initiate the file with FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Every java jvm has a working path. Usually it is the same from where the jvm is started. But you always can change this.

Your IDE has a default working path set. Depending on your IDE this can be changed in the starting options.

To find your current working path you can just print the absolute path to the current directory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
}
```

You should have your file in this folder if you are using relative path.

How ever using an absolute path should not throw any FNF exception.

---

To use the scanner you can use this example:

```
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("text.xml"));

        while (s.hasNextInt()){ 
         // bla bla
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Please handle this exception ;)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please note, that you try to invoke `hasNextInt()` on a `File` object which does not have such method. You have to invoke it on a `Scanner` object.

Comment: Hm. I think I imght've fixed it by putting a try and catch into the code. Was it not possible to open files without a try?

Comment: Sorry, i can't follow you. Please ask one question per question. Scanner throws a FileNotFoundException you have to catch this, but the error would be different then

Answer (score 1):

simple code in files use accordingly

```
BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this solution using `.getAbsolutePath()` or `.getCanonicalPath()`

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // write your code here


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = scan.nextLine();
        //FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(input);
        File file = new File(input);
        //String inputF = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "\\\\");
        String inputF = file.getCanonicalPath().replace("\\", "\\\\");


        File n = new File(inputF);
        Scanner nq = new Scanner(n);
        while (nq.hasNext()) {
            String data = nq.nextLine();
            System.out.println(data);


        }
    }
}
```

Input:
text.txt

You can visit this to understand more these methods: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-file-path-absolute-canonical